# Fastify Websocket - How to get the current connected clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, fastify

I am trying to get the current users connected to the websocket server.

this is my code register websocket

```
fastify.register(FastifyWebsocket, {
  options: {
    clientTracking: true
  }
});
```

setup fastify connection

```
  fastify.get(
    "/websocket",
    { websocket: true },
    (connection /* SocketStream */, req /* FastifyRequest */) => {
      const userToken = req.query?.userToken || req.request?.query?.userToken;
      if (userToken) {
        const userId = userIdToken(userToken);
        // Store the user ID in the connection context
        connection.socket.userId = userId;
      }

      connection.socket.on("message", (message) => {
        console.log("Web Socket - message", parseMessage(message));
      });
    }
  );
```

Then I have a function to send notification

```
/**
 * Sends a WebSocket notification to all connected clients.
 * @param {Object} payload - The payload to send as a WebSocket notification.
 * @param {String} type - The type of notification to send.
 */
export const sendGeneralNotification = function (type, payload) {
  fastify.websocketServer.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(JSON.stringify({ type, payload }));
  });
};
```

My problem is the "fastify.websocketServer.clients" is always set(0)
even when there are clients connected to the server.

How can I get the current clients connected to the server?

fastify Version:  ^4.18.0

@fastify/websocket: ^7.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the propieta clients is not present in @fastify/websocket as part of the websocketServer object, as you can see here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-websocket. I'll do some tests and tell you. In my opinion, that is where the problem lies.

Sorry for the fragmented response. Clients connected by using the connection event.

```
const connectedClients = new Set();

// Register the event handler for the "connection" event
fastify.websocketServer.on("connection", (client) => {
  connectedClients.add(client);
   
});

// Function to send a WebSocket notification to all connected clients
export const sendGeneralNotification = function (type, payload) {
  connectedClients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(JSON.stringify({ type, payload }));
  });
};
```

Comment: Here specify that you need a set that stores all connected cients:  https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#serverclients